# What is a Computer Word™?

Tags: pattern, word-property

<sub>This is in the spirit of the [What is a Word/Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22what+is+a%22+word+is%3Aquestion) series started by [JLee](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/463) with a special brand of [Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22Phrase%22%20user%3A463%20is%3Aquestion) and [Word™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22What+is+%22+%22Word%22+-missing+user%3A463+is%3Aquestion) puzzles.</sub>

---

If a word conforms to a special rule, I call it a Computer Word™.

Use the following examples below to find the rule.

[image]

And, if you want to analyze, here is a CSV version:

```
Computer Word™, Not Computer Word™
Zero, One
Adder, Arithmetic
Again, Loop
Countless, Infinite
True, False
Paths, Conditional
Processor, Graphics
Reproducible, Solid
Boolean, Integer
Yahoo, Google
```

Comment: Please clarify whether capitalization matters; In the image everything is in uppercase, but in the CSV version it's not.

Comment: @LukasRotter The case of the letters do not matter.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Computer words:

> When you add the alphabetical index of each letter, gives you a power of 2.

Examples:

> Zero -> 26 + 5 + 18 + 15 = 64 
>  Adder -> 1 + 4 + 4 + 5 + 18 = 32
>  Again -> 1 + 7 + 1 +9 + 14 = 32
>  Reproducible -> 18 + 5 +  16 + 18 + 15 + 4 + 21 + 3 + 9 +2 +12 + 5 = 128

Non Computer Words for Counterexamples:

> One -> 15 + 14 + 5 = 34
>  Loop -> 12 + 15 + 15 + 16 = 58

Comment: That is correct!

Answer (score 6):

All Computer Words:

> Have the sum of the letters converted to numbers be a power of 2. The numbers simply start with A=1 up to Z=26.

First line:

> ZERO = 26 + 5 + 18 + 15 = 64 = 2^6
>  
>  ONE = 15 + 14 + 5 = 34

Second line:

> ADDER = 1 + 4 + 4 + 5 + 18 = 32 = 2^5
>  
>  ARITHMETIC = 1 + 18 + 9 + 20 + 8 + 13 + 5 + 20 + 9 + 3 = 106

and so on...

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Puzzling.SE. Please take the [tour](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/tour). You will earn a badge.

Comment: This is correct. However, it appears someone got the correct answer a couple of minutes prior. Well done though!

Comment: Thanks, I noticed shortly after posting my answer. I should have been satisfied with one example each, that would have saved me a few minutes. ;)